# Get the value of checked radio button without re-selecting the buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am getting some buttons as follows:

```
var reportFilterButtons = $('input[name=reportfilter]', '#reportChartForm');
```

Later on this easily allows me to attach a change handler as follows:

```
reportFilterButtons.change(handlers.reportFilterButtonsChange);
```

Inside of this handler I need to get the value of the currently checked button, so I do this:

```
var checkedReportFilterButton = $('input[name=reportfilter]:checked', '#reportChartForm');
....
if (checkedReportFilterButton.val() ....
```

The `reportFilterButtons` and `checkedReportFilterButton` selectors seem redundant however.  Is there a way to get the checked/value by working against `reportFilterButtons` and not doing the second selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$.filter` to find the checked one:

```
reportFilterButtons.filter(':checked').val()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I've spent too much of the last 6.5 years doing ExtJS and not enough doing jQuery ;)

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery event listener handler `this` property points to the element that was the target of the event. This means that you don't have to find it again. Just wrap in a jQuery object $(this), and you're good to go (fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/74ayhsLr/8/)).

Code:

```
<div id="reportChartForm">
    <input type="radio" name="reportfilter" value="1">
    <label>Radio 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="reportfilter" value="2">
    <label>Radio  2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="reportfilter" value="3">
    <label>Radio  3</label>
</div>

var reportFilterButtons = $('input[name=reportfilter]', '#reportChartForm');

reportFilterButtons.change(reportFilterButtonsChange);

function reportFilterButtonsChange() {
    var value = $(this).val(); // this is the reference to the element
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: This works nicely too but am leaving the other answer as accepted as it works better in my content (I have a scoped reference to reportFilterButtons that another function that is delegated to from two different entry points can access)

Comment: Wasn't expecting :) Thanks for the thumbs up.