# Getting value from mdl radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design-lite

In the following code why doesn't the radio report the correct value when checked via its variable name?

```
var $myRadio = $('input[type=radio][name=options]:checked');

$('#button').click(() => {
  // this works
  console.log($('input[type=radio][name=options]:checked').val());
  // this doesn't :(
  console.log($myRadio.val());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/charsi/p4beztwx/13/

I am using [mdl](https://getmdl.io/) radio buttons so that could be causing it. I have also tried getting the value with `$myRadio[0].MaterialRadio.value` but that doesn't work either.

EDIT: This was a poorly worded question and didn't really have anythng to do with mdl. What I really wanted was the ability to set the DOM variable for my radio button somewhere else without having to select it by name again to check the value.

Comment: Your fiddle works. check your console. https://jsfiddle.net/bipen/p4beztwx/6/

Comment: @bipen only one of them reports the correct value. Please read my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for getting incorrect values when checked via its variable name is because you are setting `$myRadio` before the click event. `$myRadio` is set on document ready (before click event) and it gets the value of the checked radio option which at this moment is always 1.

Moving  `$myRadio` inside a click handler should work. Why? Because now it  gets the value of the radio (checked) as soon as the click function is called which is actually what you need.

```
$('#button').click(() => {
  var $myRadio = $('[id^="option"]:checked');
  // neither of these work
  alert($('input[type=radio][name=options]:checked').val());
  alert($myRadio.val());

});
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bipen/p4beztwx/8/)

Comment: hmm, thanks for the answer. makes sense. I was somehow under the impression this is not how it works for standard radio buttons. I was wrong.

Comment: Any way of assigning the variable somwhere else?

Comment: No, if you want to check the variable inside a click or change event. And why would you want to  assign variable somewhere else when you need it here . This is completely fine.

Comment: I like to declare my DOM variables once so they remain separate from the rest of the code.

Comment: Ya make sense and its a good practice but not in such case where your variable depends on some event. :)

Comment: Found what I was looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970919/get-the-value-of-checked-radio-button-without-re-selecting-the-buttons

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else running into the same issue. Not wanting to call the radio button name when checking for its value, you can use `filter` -

```
var  $myRadio = $('input[type=radio][name=options]');

$('#button').click(() => {
  console.log($myRadio.filter(':checked').val());
}
```